# Nifi 1.5.0 Cluster configuration

Tags: apache-nifi

Does anyone know how to cluster NiFi 1.5.0? I want to use dataflow.mydomain.com but... I get this error when I try to hit the loadbalancer that reads:
 "The request contained an invalid host header [dataflow.mydomain.com] in the request [/nifi/]. Check for request manipulation or third-party intercept."

According to one post that I read, the problem was that the value of nifi.web.http.host had to match the value of the url.

If that's true, I don't understand how a cluster would be possible.

Thanks!

(I'm using a 3 host setup in AWS, the hosts will individually respond if I set the nifi.web.http.host to their private IP and I access it at http://[ip]/nifi/
but not if I use a loadbalancer in front of the cluster).

Answer (score 2):

It is not really an issue of clustering NiFi, it is an issue of accessing it through a load balancer. A cluster does not imply a load balancer.

In the next version of NiFi there will be a new property (nifi.web.proxy.host) where you could put dataflow.mydomain.com and it would let it through.

For now I think you'd have to strip off the host header of each request at your load balancer so that it doesn't get passed on to the NiFi nodes, that it was is triggering the rejection. NiFi is inspecting the headers of the incoming request and seeing that the host header has a value that is not the host of NiFi.

Comment: fair point, it seems that no matter what configurations I use though, my nodes aren't communicating with each other despite using identical zookeeper connection strings. I guess my problem is 1) The nodes aren't forming a cluster and 2) when they do, they'll either need a) a proxy to strip out the headers, or b) to be accessed individually.


I've read many pages of documentation, is there a good resource for identifying/troubleshooting my first issue?

Comment: You can access the UI from any node, it is still showing you the view of the whole cluster and anything you change will take affect on all nodes, so the only reason to need a load balancer in front of the UI is if you have a lot of users and want to spread them across the nodes.

Comment: There are a lot of different posts about setting up a cluster... https://pierrevillard.com/2016/08/13/apache-nifi-1-0-0-cluster-setup/ https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#clustering http://nixtutorials.com/2017/01/11/setup-apache-nifi-cluster/

Comment: Also, you'll want to set nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=  to something like the number of nodes in your cluster, or some majority like 2 for a 3 node cluster, otherwise it will take 5 mins to form the cluster by default.

Comment: Bryan - I understand that when correctly setup the cluster will be accessible from any node, my issue is that I don't want to have my users enter in http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/nifi/ and using a cname won't work due to nifi 1.5.0's header restriction. I'd like failover to be seamless at the same address such that even if a node fails, nifi.mydomain.com still works. But I don't see a way to do that with the header restriction.